# Link static HTML, Javascript and CSS3 in a Drupal Site

Tags: javascript, theming, path-aliases

I am trying to have collaborative development of a HTML5 web app which people could navigate too through my drupal site. I was planning on putting the html, JS and CSS3 files in my sites/default/files folder and just passing a link. I am curious how i perform to things

How can I put an alias over the html file so i can have url mysite/demo 
also I want to block people from reading my JS and CSS3 files so the source code is just not purely out in the open is there a way to do this.

I know inspect html on most browsers give you a lot but I do not want them to find my .js file and then request that and have my source code.

Any assistance or guidance would be very helpful

Comment: If you are going to down grade me at least explain why. I think this is a novel question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for what your describing is to take a screen shot of the site and use that; as an image will not display the html/css/js. https://www.drupal.org/project/phantomjs_capture is the project I would use; this is a very odd request so in order to achieve this you'll have to do some custom coding.

If your looking to obfuscate the JavaScript by minification [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg/) can help but it's not setup to fully obfuscate the JS as it will point to the source file by default (for GPL compliance). This could be changed; if you do decide to go down this route open up a request in the advagg issue queue and I'll add in a hidden option to allow this to happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am stuck between a rock and a hard place as I want people to see where I am at but not steal my source code. I will check out your suggestions.

Comment: im using 7.x-2.7, is the fully obfuscate available now? or can you point me which part of the code i should look into it? Thanks!

Comment: @Kent The latest dev has it and 2.8 will be coming out very soon. Drupal.org is actaully using the dev version currently. Go to admin/config/development/performance/advagg/js-compress and uncheck "Add licensing comments".